# PowerBI Modelling, Many-to-many relationship

Tags: powerbi, many-to-many, dax, modeling

When modelling these three tables, I get many-to-many relations. Country is the only column similar in all three tables but when I use "country" to get the relationships, I get many-to-many. The unique column in wine is ID, in Olympics Olympian ID and in Happiness, its Country. How do I resolve this? Please see the pic attached[image]

I tried using "county" column to create the relationship between the three tables

Comment: What question are you trying to answer with this data model?  Why are those three tables even in the same data model?  They appear to be unreleated.

Answer (score 0):

You will get many to many when you have more than one of the same value on both sides of the relationship.
What you need to do is create a new table for Country and ensure this has unique values. Then you can create a relationship for each of the three tables to the new Country table.

To create the Country table, in PowerQuery, append the three tables together, drop all columns except for Country, then finally do a Remove Duplicates.